# enabling / disabling components from editor, while avoiding "SendMessage" warning

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I am creating an editor tool that requires me to enable / disable components and or gameObjects via script while in edit mode. Currently everything that has to execute in edit mode is called from `OnValidate()`

When calling either `gameObject.SetActive(...)` or `component.enabled(...)` from `OnValidate` I get the following warning:

```
SendMessage cannot be called during Awake, CheckConsistency, or OnValidate (Scrample: OnBecameInvisible)
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
```

From what I can tell from googling, in particular [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/sendmessage-cannot-be-called-during-awake-checkconsistency-or-onvalidate-can-we-suppress.537265/) thread, this is expected behaviour.

If that is the case, what would be the best way to enable / disable stuff via script when in edit mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way I got around this was to set a bool in `OnValidate` that is checked in Update. You will need to add the compiler directive `[ExecuteAlways]` in front of the class declaration. This causes the `Update` method to run in the editor.

```
void OnValidate()
{
    if (bInspectorVar == true)
    {
        //set flags for use in Update
        bUpdateFlag1 = true
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if(bUpdateFlag1==true)
    {
        //do instantiation/destroyimmediate here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, DMGregory